# Loop for starting month and starting year to end month and year python

Tags: python, pandas, date, for-loop, calendar

**Database df:**

```
month    year   data
Jan      2017    ggg
Feb      2015    jhjj
Jan      2018    hjhj
Mar      2018    hjhj

and so on
```

**Code:**

```
def data_from_start_month_to_end_month:
    for y in range(start_year,end_year):
        do something 
        for m in range(start_month,13):
            df = df[(df['month'] == m)&(df['year']== y)]
    return df
```

This will start the code from the starting month and year but what if end month is not December, then it wont work.

**Output  I want:**

```
start_month = Sep 
start_year = 2000
end_month = Feb
end_year = 2019 say
```

**So loop should work from Sep 2000 to Feb 2019 and extract the data only for those rows.** (but I need the function to be generic and not hard coded

Can anyone help

Comment: You need to combine the month and year columns to create a Series of [datetime Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#overview) - then make datetime objects for your beginning and end dates, then do comparisons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below function which uses [`series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) after converting the inputs to datetime:

```
def myf(df,start_month,start_year,end_month,end_year):
    s= pd.to_datetime(df['month']+df['year'].astype(str),format='%b%Y')
    start = pd.to_datetime(start_month+str(start_year),format='%b%Y')
    end = pd.to_datetime(end_month+str(end_year),format='%b%Y')
    return df[s.between(start,end)]
```

---

```
myf(df,'Sep',2000,'Feb',2017)

  month  year  data
0   Jan  2017   ggg
1   Feb  2015  jhjj
```

If month is number , use `format='%m%Y'` instead of `format='%b%Y'`:

```
def myf1(df,start_month,start_year,end_month,end_year):
    s= pd.to_datetime(df['month'].astype(str)+df['year'].astype(str),format='%m%Y')
    start = pd.to_datetime(start_month+str(start_year),format='%b%Y')
    end = pd.to_datetime(end_month+str(end_year),format='%b%Y')
    return df[s.between(start,end)]
```

Example df:

```
   month  year  data
0      1  2017   ggg
1      2  2015  jhjj
2      1  2018  hjhj
3      3  2018  hjhj

myf1(df,'Sep',2000,'Feb',2017)

   month  year  data
0      1  2017   ggg
1      2  2015  jhjj
```

Comment: What if the month is in numbers lets say 1,2.....12 etc. Then how will this work

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor it is achievable by just changing the format parameter, but need confirmation: so if month is in numbers you want to still input `Jan` as input parameter and not 1?

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor edited my answer. You can get all formatting tips from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)